# RUBY delete item in a loop

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'd like to delete an item in my loop
i have a array of instance of my class, and i need sometimes to delete this items from my array

```
class Test
    attr_reader :to_del
    def initialize(str)
        @to_del = str
    end
end

tab = Array.new

a = Test.new(false)
b = Test.new(true)
c = Test.new(false)

tab.push(a)
tab.push(b)
tab.push(c)

for l in tab

    if l.to_del == true
        l = nil
    end

end

p tab
```

any idea ?

Comment: Note you can just write `tab = [Test.new(false), Test.new(true), Test.new(false)]`. As you gain experience with Ruby you'll find that `for` is very rarely used. (I've never used it.) That's because it's almost always better to employ a method that enumerates the elements of the receiver (here an array), as has been done by in both answers so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For inplace deletion:

```
tab.reject! { |l| l.to_del }
```

to return just a cleared array:

```
tab.reject &:to_del
```

The whole code is php-smelled. I would go with:

```
tab = (1..3).map { [true,false].sample }.map { |e| Test.new e }
tab.reject &:to_del
```

Comment: And there's the fancy `tab.reject!(&:to_del)` shortcut.

Comment: @Max not only is it "fancy" `Symbol#to_proc` is actually faster than using an explicit block.

Comment: @engineersmnky Wrong. The behavior varies. `Benchmark.bm { |x| x.report { n.times { [1,2,3].map { |i| i.to_s } } } ; x.report { n.times { [1,2,3].map &:to_s } } }` ⇒ `[2.39, 2.71]`. Please don’t make unfounded declarations.

Comment: I prefer `Array.new(3) { ... }` or `3.times.map { ... }` to `(1..3).map { ... }` since the indices aren't important.

Comment: @engineersmnky I clearly said: *it depends*. I never said lambda is faster. I stated that your declaration “`#to_proc` is faster” is just wrong *in general*.

Comment: @Max `(1..3)` ⇒ 6 symbols to input. `3.times` ⇒ 7 symbols. `Array.new(3)` ⇒ 12. :)

Comment: @engineersmnky Care to provide a prooflink? Otherwise I will consider you a regular troll.

Comment: @mudasobwa sure [Here](http://goo.gl/UAE7nn) just click execute and you will see that the explicit block is only fastest when the Array has very few elements (even this is not always true which leads me back to my original statement that `Symbol#to_proc` is faster). You can still consider me a troll if you'd like but my statements are not without empirical evidence.

Comment: @mudasobwa This isn't code golf. `3.times` and `Array.new(3)` are more semantic.

Comment: Also I would like to point out I am not the only one who is willing to make this "unfounded declaration". See [fast-ruby](https://github.com/JuanitoFatas/fast-ruby) on GitHub and Erik Michaels-Ober's [Speech at the Barcelona Ruby Conference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGFM_UrSp70). start at 14:30 he states `Symbol#to_proc` is actually 20% faster than block. So....

Comment: @Max why not play some golf if he wants `(['',nil] * 3).sample(3).map{ |e| Test.new !!e}` saves me a whole 7 characters. What will I do with all my free time :)

Comment: `3.times.map{Test.new !![nil,1].sample}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array#`delete_if`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/delete_if).

Check this out:

```
tab
#=> [#<Test:0x00000007548768 @to_del=false>, #<Test:0x000000074ea348 @to_del=true>, #<Test:0x000000074b21a0 @to_del=false>]
tab.delete_if {|x| x.to_del}
#=> [#<Test:0x00000007548768 @to_del=false>, #<Test:0x000000074b21a0 @to_del=false>]
```